# superset elasticsearch timestamp formats

Tags: elasticsearch, sqlalchemy, apache-superset

I know that superset dbapi  is based on python sqlalchemy,
and elsticsearch-dbapi use json parser, on my ELK indices timestamp are formatted as:

```
2021-01-09T11:41:00.127Z
```

and the column type is string not date, how is it possible to get filterable date timestmap ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

nobody answered this question,
but magically on 20th April:

> https://github.com/preset-io/elasticsearch-dbapi/releases/tag/0.2.3

```
pip3 install --upgrade elasticsearch-dbapi
```

... and ...
datetime columns are managed as expected, (in the mean time  in a galaxy far, far away.)

```
pip3 install --upgrade apache-superset
```

upgraded to version 1.1.1